# Создание и подключение библиотеки DLL c++.error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ

Tags: c++, dll, export

Всем привет. Я пробую создать и подключить свою DLL. Не могу понять, почему вижуалка не видит мои функции. Хотя определения есть, ссылка тоже указана на библиотеку. Может кто-то знает?

Заголовочный файл **MyMathFuncs.h**:

```
#define DllExport   __declspec( dllexport ) 

namespace MathFuncs
{
    class MyMathFuncs
    {
    public:
        static double Add(double a, double b);
        static double Subtract(double a, double b);
        static double Multiply(double a, double b);
    };
}
```

Файл **MyMathFuncs.cpp**:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MyMathFuncs.h"
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

namespace MathFuncs
{
    double MyMathFuncs::Add(double a, double b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    double MyMathFuncs::Subtract(double a, double b)
    {
        return a - b;
    }

    double MyMathFuncs::Multiply(double a, double b)
    {
        return a * b;
    }
}
```

Файл **MyExecRefsDll.cpp**:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "MyMathFuncs.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double a = 7.4;
    int b = 99;

    cout << "a + b = " <<
        MathFuncs::MyMathFuncs::Add(a, b) << endl;
    cout << "a - b = " <<
        MathFuncs::MyMathFuncs::Subtract(a, b) << endl;
    cout << "a * b = " <<
        MathFuncs::MyMathFuncs::Multiply(a, b) << endl;
    cout << "a / b = ";

    return 0;
}
```

Вот такие ошибки:

error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы просто объявили функции. Для экспорта нужно о объявить примерно так: `static __declspec(dllexport) double Functions()`, вроде так.

Comment: не вариант, ничего не меняется

Comment: Зачем вы определили макро `DllExport`, если оно нигде никак не используется?

Comment: Удалите static, static не экспортируется.

Comment: Если static убрать, то будет эта ошибка: C2352 MathFuncs::MyMathFuncs::Add: недопустимый вызов нестатической функции-члена

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по [этой статье](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/81h27t8c.aspx), нужно что-то на подобие этого:

В `MyMathFuncs.h`:

```
#ifndef MY_LIB
#define MY_LIB __declspec( dllimport )
#endif

// ...

class MY_LIB MyMathFuncs {/*...*/};

// ...
```

В `MyMathFuncs.cpp`:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#define MY_LIB __declspec( dllexport )
#include "MyMathFuncs.h"

// ...
```

Comment: тоже не помогает